# Best practice for designing rest service with sub-elements

Tags: rest, service

I'm designing a REST service that requires the creation of an item that references various other items as children. The service provides methods for retrieving the available children as options that can be bound to a drop-down as key/value pairs. My question is, when posting to create the new top-level item, is it best practice to include the entire child item in the field or just the ID that references it?

For example, if I had a service that enabled a user to specify a processor and RAM for a laptop. There would be a method GET `/processors` that would return the list of processors and POST `/laptops` that would trigger the object creation. Which of the two payloads below is considered to be best practice?

POST /laptops

```
{
    "processor": 123,
    "ram" 16
}
```

POST /laptops

```
{
    "processor": {"id":123, "manufacturer": "Intel", "model": "i5-4670k"}
    "ram" 16
}
```

When retrieving the laptops I would return something like this:

GET /laptops

```
[{
    "id:" 3000,
    "processor": {"id":123, "manufacturer": "Intel", "model": "i5-4670k"}
    "ram" 16
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the parts that are used to construct a laptop are predefined (or already existing) it's better idea to use only the ID of the part. So it will be:

POST /laptops

```
{
    "processorID": 123
}
```

Why? Because this way you save the bandwidth and simplify the validation on the server side as well. Instead of checking all the fields of a processor you just check only if process with given ID exists - if not `409 CONFLICT` should be returned.

If you want to enable the user to **create** the parts during laptop creation then the whole body of a particular part should be sent. However this is not a good idea. In a RESTful approach you should create all the parts and then create a laptop - which points to the previous paragraph.

The most important thing is to design the API in a consistent way - in the same way in the all endpoints.

Now, when it comes to returning a laptop it would be good idea to return only ID as well. This approach will be compatible with creating new entity (only ID sent) but bandwidth argument may be a little misleading - client will need to make multiple requests to get the details of all the parts. So.. In this case I will add query param named `format` which accepts two values `SIMPLE` (default) and `EXTENDED`. If `SIMPLE` is passed only ID is returned whether if `EXTENDED` is passed then the whole entity is returned.